# Firemonkey deployment folders on a Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, delphi, firemonkey, dylib

I am new to Mac development and are trying to understand the location that XE2 firemonkey apps are deployed. I understand that the application is deployed into a "package" however I am not sure how this work when getting path information from within my app.

My application loads a dylib that I moved over from Visual Studio to XCode and initializes it by passing in a driver path (intended to be off the application path). i.e.
    UDMXLibInit(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(driver_path))

If I put a breakpoint on this line in Delphi I find that driver_path is:
 .../PAServer/scratch-dir/MacMini/LightFactory3.app/Content/MacOS/drivers

In my dylib I put a breakpoint in XCode on the "Init" function I find that the path is now:
 .../PAServer/scratch-dir/MacMini/LightFactory3.app/Content

There appears to be some vodo that is truncating the path. Is this because "LightFactory3.app" is a package and there is something I dont understand or is there something else I am missing about passing this string between app and library under OSX?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you put dylibs in the Contents/MacOS folder in the application bundle, you don't have to specify a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the Expressions view for XCode 3.2. For some reason it truncates strings.
The actual string was correct - figure this out by passing it back to to my app.